# java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: when using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
public static <A, B> B convert(A instance,
                           Class<B> targetClass) throws Exception {
  B target = (B)targetClass.newInstance();

  for (Field targetField : targetClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    targetField.setAccessible(true);
    Field field =
        instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(targetField.getName());
    field.setAccessible(true);
    targetField.set(target, field.get(instance));
  }
  return target;
}
```

Above is the code I get from forum, When I try to reflect an single type object it works, but when I try on the complex type which mean inside `ClassA` I got `ClassB` object, I got the `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: by the way, the general policy of using Stackoverflow is to mark an answer as "accepted" (the tick below the votes on each answer) whenever it suits you.

Comment: Where is the stack trace, by the way?

Comment: @Bozho: Good suggestion in advance ;)

Comment: @Bozho: agree if there is accepted of course

Comment: @newbie123: then please review your history of recent asked questions - you haven's accepted a single answer so far.

Comment: That is because no answer is exactly I want

Comment: `targetField.setAccessible(true);` seen that somewhere... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950429/java-reflect-2-objects/1957614#1957614

Comment: 1) NoSuchFieldException should contain the field name that was not found, which one was it?  . . . 
2) How are the fields of ClassA and ClassB declared? How is/are the ClassC declared? better append it to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You have two different classes, with, most likely, different set of fields.
So if your Class `A` doesn't have the same fields as your class `B`, then the exception is thrown.

I'd suggest using [`BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target)`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) from [apache commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). You just create the second object yourself, and pass it to the method. It will not throw an exception if fields differ.

What is your ultimate goal with this piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestion:

(1) You can drop the downcast at the first line of the method:

```
B target = targetClass.newInstance();
```

(2) Add a try catch so that you can see the name of the missing field. This will help you sort out the issue you're having:

```
 Field field = null;
 try {
    field = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(targetField.getName());
 }
 catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Didn't find field named '" + targetField.getName() + "'");
 }
 ...
```

Comment: both method give me java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. By the way thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer.

If I understand your comment correctly it seems that you have inner classes: Class B (Target) is a class that is defined inside class A. Something like this:

```
 class A {
   int n;

   class B { 
      int n;
   }
}
```

Although these two classes seem to have the same fields, and therefore - should not inude a field not found error - they are not.

Inner classes (unless they are defined as static) has a hidden field inserted by the compiler. This field is of the type of the outer class and points to the object that created the inner class object. When using reflection this field is exposed. As A does not have such field, an exception is raised.

Comment: Ya I have a inner class in ClassA which is ClassC but in ClassB also have ClassC ClassA and ClassB have exactly the same attriutes.