# Java NoSuchFieldError when using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, field, final

I'm trying to modify a public static final String[] field I made in ClassA, and then modify it in ClassB using reflection. However I get a NoSuchFieldException.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: test
at java.lang.Class.getField(Unknown Source)
at packageA.ClassA.<init>(ClassA.java:17)
```

`ClassA` is located in `packageA` and `ClassB` is located in `packageB` if that matters.

`Class A`, creates the field and calls `ClassB`:

```
package packageA;

import packageB.ClassB;

public class ClassA {
    // Create final String[]
    public static final String[] test = new String[] {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};

    public ClassA() {
        // Output array content before change
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(test[i]);
        }

        // Change array content
        try {
            new ClassB(String[].class.getField("test"), new String[] {"Change1", "Change2", "Change3"});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Output array content after change
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(test[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Class B, Modifies the 'test' array:

```
package packageB;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class ClassB {

    public ClassB(Field field, Object newValue) {
        try {
            field.setAccessible(true);

            Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
            modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
            modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

            field.set(null, newValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I got ClassB from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection) and I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026369/java-lang-nosuchfieldexception-when-using-reflection) post but I couldn't find anything that worked.

From what i've gathered from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026369/java-lang-nosuchfieldexception-when-using-reflection) topic, I think the exception means that it doesn't know what 'test' is in ClassB and that I haven't initialized it in ClassB, but I couldn't really figure that out.

Comment: Use `new ClassB(ClassA.class.getField("test"),.....` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String[].class.getField("test")` throws a `NoSuchFieldException` because this field does not exist in `String[]`, it exists in `packageA.ClassA`.

`ClassA.class.getField("test")` will return the correct field access.

Comment: Thanks [Paul](http://stackoverflow.com/users/697449/paul-bellora), my English is really approximative ;-)