# "java.lang.ClassCastException" error while running scalatest through maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, scalatest-maven-plugin

I run my test cases successfully through Intellij.
But I got the "java.lang.ClassCastException" error when I run scalatest through "mvn test" command.

It's really weird. The reason might be that my scala program calls java program because some of the pure scala test cases don't have this kind of error.
Does someone know how to fix this issue?

```
Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD   at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287) at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2293) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)  ...
```

Also here is the part of my pom.xml

````
       <pluginManagement>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.7</version>
               </plugin>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                   <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>1.0</version>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </pluginManagement>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <skipTests>true</skipTests>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
               <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                   <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                   <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>test</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>test</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
               <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>compile</goal>
                           <goal>testCompile</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>true</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
                   <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                   <filters>
                       <filter>
                           <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                           <excludes>
                               <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                               <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                               <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                           </excludes>
                       </filter>
                   </filters>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>shade</goal>
                       </goals>

                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>log4j-plugin-processor</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>compile</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <phase>process-classes</phase>
                       <configuration>
                           <proc>only</proc>
                           <annotationProcessors>
                               <annotationProcessor>
                                   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.processor.PluginProcessor
                               </annotationProcessor>
                           </annotationProcessors>
                           <source>8</source>
                           <target>8</target>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>```
````

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can also try to run Scalatest from terminal to make sure that the issue is how Maven runs Scalatest. Something like `scala -cp scalatest_2.13-3.2.0.jar org.scalatest.run ExampleSpec` https://www.scalatest.org/ For example I had https://stackoverflow.com/a/63993917/5249621

Comment: If Scalatest runs in terminal successfully, bug report about ScalaTest Maven Plugin should be sent here https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-maven-plugin/issues